# select min and max column value from each part of table base of other column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that show each Employee when present in one Office.
The sample SQL table EmpPTable name is like this:

| id | EmployeeID | DateP | TimeP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 1397/01/02 | 01:30 |
| 2 | 11111 | 1398/05/09 | 05:30 |
| 3 | 11111 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 |
| 4 | 22222 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 |
| 5 | 22222 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 |
| 6 | 11111 | 1399/07/02 | 08:51 |
| 7 | 11111 | 1399/08/06 | 12:20 |
| 8 | 33333 | 1399/09/04 | 20:01 |
| 9 | 33333 | 1399/12/08 | 22:05 |
| 10 | 33333 | 1400/01/01 | 23:11 |
| 11 | 33333 | 1400/02/05 | 14:10 |
| 12 | 22222 | 1400/04/05 | 16:25 |

I want exactly select Min and Max date for each Employee when present in a office:

| id | EmployeeID | MinDateP | MaxDateP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 1397/01/02 | 1398/06/07 |
| 2 | 22222 | 1398/08/09 | 1399/02/01 |
| 3 | 11111 | 1399/07/02 | 1399/08/06 |
| 4 | 33333 | 1399/09/04 | 1400/02/05 |
| 5 | 22222 | 1400/04/05 | 1400/04/05 |

My SQL code for give max value is:

```
       SELECT EmployeeID,MinDateP
        FROM (
          SELECT EmployeeID
          FROM EmpPTable
          GROUP BY EmployeeID
        ) As rstOuter
        OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 DateP As MinDateP
          FROM EmpPTable As rstInner
          WHERE rstInner.EmployeeID = rstOuter.EmployeeID
          ORDER BY DateP
        ) AS rstMinPoints
```

SQL code for give min date employee present is:

```
        SELECT EmployeeID,MaxDateP
        FROM (
          SELECT EmployeeID
          FROM EmpPTable
          GROUP BY EmployeeID
        ) As rstOuter
        OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 DateP As MaxDateP
          FROM EmpPTable As rstInner
          WHERE rstInner.EmployeeID = rstOuter.EmployeeID
          ORDER BY DateP desc
        ) AS rstMinPoints
```

But above codes give min and max date column for each Employee from all table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should build a `group by` column

mysql5.8

```sql
with tab1 as (
select 1 id, 1 user_id, '2021-11-01' dat from dual union all
select 2 id, 1 user_id, '2021-11-02' dat from dual union all
select 3 id, 1 user_id, '2021-11-03' dat from dual union all
select 4 id, 2 user_id, '2021-11-04' dat from dual union all
select 5 id, 2 user_id, '2021-11-05' dat from dual union all
select 6 id, 1 user_id, '2021-11-06' dat from dual union all
select 7 id, 1 user_id, '2021-11-07' dat from dual union all
select 8 id, 1 user_id, '2021-11-08' dat from dual union all
select 9 id, 3 user_id, '2021-11-09' dat from dual 
)
, tab2 as (
select t1.*,
       case when lag(t1.user_id) over(order by t1.id) is null then 1
            when lag(t1.user_id) over(order by t1.id) = t1.user_id then 0
            else 1
       end lg
  from tab1 t1
)
, tab3 as (
select t1.*,
       sum(t1.lg) over(order by t1.id) grp
  from tab2 t1
)
select t1.user_id,
       min(t1.dat),
       max(t1.dat)
  from tab3 t1
 group by t1.user_id, t1.grp
```

Comment: Hi,Thank's but I couldn't understand your code because I need SQL code for SQL server 2012 and I didn't catch dual table. can you help me?

Comment: You only need to delete all the `from dual`   [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bc63b/361](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bc63b/361)

Comment: Hi,Very good,Many Thanks. I  I was searching in the internet for a few days. But I use sql express 2008 r2 and Lag function don't work in. Can you help me how use that code in sql express  2008?    thanks a lot

Comment: Each analysis function can be replaced by a self-join, which applies to all versions. Regarding the replacement method, this is a common question, you can easily find the answer on the Internet, such as this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540642/how-to-use-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540642/how-to-use-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your code as there are some fields missing (serial1?). But here is my solution.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempEmployee (
    ID INT,
    EmployeeID INT,
    EmpDate DATE,
    EmpTime TIME
);

INSERT INTO #tempEmployee VALUES (1, '11111', '2021-01-10', '12:30');
INSERT INTO #tempEmployee VALUES (1, '11111', '2021-12-10', '12:33');
INSERT INTO #tempEmployee VALUES (1, '11111', '2021-11-10', '12:30');
INSERT INTO #tempEmployee VALUES (2, '22222', '2021-01-11', '12:30');
INSERT INTO #tempEmployee VALUES (2, '22222', '2021-11-11', '12:30');

SELECT * FROM #tempEmployee;

WITH MaxDate AS (SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(EmpDate) AS MaxEmpDate FROM #tempEmployee GROUP BY EmployeeID),
     MinDate AS (SELECT EmployeeID, MIN(EmpDate) AS MinEmpDate FROM #tempEmployee GROUP BY EmployeeID)

     SELECT n.EmployeeID,
            n.MinEmpDate,
            x.MaxEmpDate
        FROM MinDate n 
        INNER JOIN MaxDate x ON n.EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID
        ORDER BY n.EmployeeID;

DROP TABLE #tempEmployee;
```

Outputs....

```
EmployeeID  MinEmpDate  MaxEmpDate
11111       2021-01-10  2021-12-10
22222       2021-01-11  2021-11-11
```

Comment: Hi ,Many Thanks for your solution, but I need min and max value for each employee base date, I edit my question and my sql code. can you help me?

Comment: So you need the interval for each date? I don't seem to fully understand your question. The "primary" key of your query (so to say) would be the date interval, not the employee.

Comment: Table primary key is id, I can`t put date column as primary key because dates maybe are the same,I just find each employee when present and other employee when present.I want this result |id|EmployeeID|MinDateP|MaxDateP|
|---|---|---|---|
|1|11111|1397/01/02|1398/06/07|
|2|22222|1398/08/09|1399/02/01|
|3|11111|1399/07/02|1399/08/06|
|4|33333|1399/09/04|1400/02/05|
|5|22222|1400/04/05|1400/04/05|