# select / update SQL records that has a timestamp difference of more then 30 days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select or update records from badge-records that have a date difference of more than 30 days after the last visit. A select query to find them is ok, so I can update them.
Difficult to explain in detail but I'll try with an example:
(This is an access system where people scan a badge and the timestamp is recorded.)
I only need to know the records when a badge has entered the system more than 30 days after the previous scan, + the very first scan.
The example table is showing the records I need from the table (i need 5 records)

Only records of the same badge number must be compared and updated.

Is this possible using TSQL ?

Example:

```
+------------------+--------------+
| TimeStamp        | Badge        |
+------------------+--------------+
| 19-10-2022 10:18 | Badge1       | <--- **select** (more the 30 days after previous scan)
| 01-01-2022 12:18 | Badge1       | <--- ok (less then 30 days)
| 08-12-2021 13:23 | Badge1       | <--- ok (less then 30 days)
| 20-11-2021 11:18 | Badge1       | <--- ok (less then 30 days)
| 22-10-2021 13:18 | Badge1       | <--- **select** (more the 30 days after previous scan)
| 23-08-2020 14:18 | Badge1       | <--- **select** (first entrance)
| 01-01-2022 09:18 | Badge12      | <--- ok (less then 30 days)
| 02-12-2021 10:18 | Badge12      | <--- **select** (more the 30 days after previous scan)
| 29-10-2021 23:18 | Badge12      | <--- ok (less then 30 days)
| 25-10-2021 12:18 | Badge12      | <--- **select** (first entrance)
+------------------+---------+----+
```

use this fiddle to have the example db and my wrong answer  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1528618004f0fe6bb6319e8e638abae

Comment: This would be **much** easier if you were on a supported version of SQL Server. Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? It has been *completely* unsupported for over 3 years now.

Comment: yes i know, sorry for that. it's an old system but still does the job

Comment: I would argue it doesn't when, as I mentioned, the version has been *completely* unsupported for over *3 years*, and the tool you want (`LAG`/`LEAD`) doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008. You really should be a long way down your upgrade path and close to getting off the version. You'll need to use a self lateral join here.

Comment: i know LAG is not  available to versions prior to 2012. but ROW_NUMBER with a self join can replace that. May I say it's challenging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use LAG FUNCTION in SQL SERVER 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540642/how-to-use-lag-function-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1528618004f0fe6bb6319e8e638abae  i tried this

Answer (score 0):

Help others help you. Post a script that contains DDL and sample data that can be used as the basis for writing code.

```
with cte as (
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Badge order by Timestamp) as rno
   from @x 
)
select cte.*, prior.rno as prno, datediff(day, prior.TimeStamp, cte.Timestamp) as ddif
from cte
left join cte as prior on cte.badge = prior.badge and cte.rno - 1 = prior.rno
where cte.rno = 1 or datediff(day, prior.TimeStamp, cte.Timestamp) > 30
order by cte.Badge, cte.TimeStamp;
```

This should work but I have no way of testing on 2008. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f59d82d0cf05ec599ccd176ec6bfefe4) to demonstrate. Comment out the WHERE clause to see the all the rows and the columns that are computed for the query logic. This uses ROW_NUMBER to generate a sequence number and then simply self joins using that value to simulate LAG.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1528618004f0fe6bb6319e8e638abae  you can use this fiddle

Answer (score 0):

updated fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a24d23f54030d7aadd8f889819cd4512

```
;WITH Ordered AS (
    SELECT *
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Badge ORDER BY  CONVERT(DATETIME, [scandate] ,103) DESC) rn
    FROM History 
) 
SELECT M.*, DATEDIFF(dd,  p.[scandate],m.[scandate]) DaysGap
FROM Ordered M
LEFT JOIN  Ordered P 
ON M.rn = P.rn-1 
AND M.Badge = P.Badge 
WHERE P.rn IS NULL -- first entrance
OR DATEDIFF(dd,  p.[scandate],m.[scandate]) > 30
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this is great, but how can i update some fields in those selected records now in the history table?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b87a386cedfcb459c86ea3ccac87b0e7
for example i need to add 1 to the score on only the selected rows

Comment: that should be very simple, just change the select statement to your intended UPDATE.  
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c9e5cbf86b1ca348bcd240685beb0cb  Please mark it answered if your question was answered.